# Wrong DateTime in created_at and updated_at fields in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5

I am using jenssegers mongodb
I am trying to save created_at and updated_at in my controller,

```
"updated_at" : ISODate("1970-01-11T19:45:21.925Z"),
"created_at" : ISODate("1970-01-11T19:45:21.925Z")
```

and even for update also, the wrong dates are saving

in my app.php

in aliases

```
'Moloquent' => 'Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model',
```

in providers

```
'Jenssegers\Mongodb\Auth\PasswordResetServiceProvider',
```

in my model

```
use Moloquent;

class Task extends Moloquent{
      //$fillables = [];
}
```

[image]

Please help me in solving the issue
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using `jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB` package? Also, why do you want manually set created_at and updated_at (as it's automatically set on creation time)?

Comment: commented created_at and updated_at in insert, and saved in db "updated_at" : ISODate("1970-01-15T17:25:44.107Z"),
"created_at" : ISODate("1970-01-15T17:25:44.107Z")

unable to fetch the data, also why the dates are wrong @felipsmartins

Comment: why do you want manually set created_at and updated_at?

Comment: I actually don't know that they will create automatically, so I did. Thanks

Comment: Also, please tell me why my dates are wrong in the database ISODate("1970-01-15T17:25:44.107Z")

I want to update the same record. updated_at is required or not while updating? Please tell

Comment: In fact that fields are created automatically so you don't need set it. However, if you still want to do it let me know and I'll post the answer bellow.

Comment: I want to update the updated_at field while updating the row. Will it update the updated_at field without placing it? Please check the wrong dates also

Answer (score 2):

Actually - when using  `jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB` package - **created_at** and **updated_at** attributes are automatically set when saving a new model object.

However if you still want manually set timestamps or anything else datetime field you MUST convert a DateTime object (or Carbon) to `MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime`.

So it would be something like this:

```
$myModel = new MyModel();
$myModel->created_at = $myModel->fromDateTime(new \DateTime());
//...
```

And for another datetime attribute other than created_at/updated_at:

```
class Task extends Model
{
    protected  $collection = 'tasks';

    protected $duedate;

    protected  $dates = ['duedate'];

    /** Mutator */
    public function setDuedateAttribute($value)
    {
        /** @var \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime */
        $this->attributes['duedate'] = $this->fromDateTime(
            \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $value . '00:00'));
    }
}
```

`Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent::fromDateTime()` is available from any model instance as it inherits from parent model (see in [github](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/blob/master/src/Jenssegers/Mongodb/Eloquent/Model.php#L149)). This method convert a DateTime to a storable UTCDateTime object (which is the internal datetime mongo rep).

Comment: Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent::fromDateTime(), where should I add this?

Comment: thanks for the help. But can you please help me in getting the exact date. My dates are saving as 1970-01-15

Comment: please don't mind I am irritating you. The mutator you have created in the model for duedates. I don't want any additional field to save dates. I am saving dates in created_at and updated_at fields. the github link is not helping me. Is it required to create mutators for created_at and updated_at?

Comment: @Gireesh Never mind! ;) Well... just like I said before *created_at* and *updated_at* attrbutes are automatically set when saving a model, so you shouldn't have any problem.

Comment: They are automatically saving, but with wrong date. How to correct that?

Comment: @Gireesh Well... that is pretty weird. My current app works well. Are you sure your model is extending from `\Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model`?

Comment: I am extending Moloquent, 
in my app.php 'Moloquent' => 'Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model',
in my Model, use Moloquent,
class Task extends Moloquent

I used like this

Comment: https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/783, the same issue I am facing. No answers for this @felipsmartins